# Website shows which Powerball ticket combos have been picked

Tags: internet, trademark

Recently it has been big news that the Powerball lottery has grown to record jackpot sizes and if no winner by Saturday it could hit 2 billion dollars. There are roughly 2.92 million possible combinations to pick from and last I saw an article stated almost 85% of all possible combinations have been bought. However, I assume many of those must be duplicate combinations.

I was wondering, would it be legal to make a website that allowed users to submit which combination they purchased and find other combos not yet purchased? I assume if this was widely adopted the lottery would lose money as the jackpot would end faster as it would be less likely a winning number would go unpurchased.

I would obviously claim no affiliation but Powerball is a trademarked name. What if I found a way to serve the same purpose without using their name. What if I used ads that let me make money off of this website?

Without getting into discussion on usefullness of this or whether this would affect anyone's odds what would be the legal ramifications to a site like this?

Comment: Seems to me that a site which factors combinations of 7 numbers doesn't have anything to do with Powerball unless you say it does. I mean there are sites like: https://www.usamega.com/powerball-quickpicks.asp and http://www.powerball.com/powerball/pb_frequency.asp

Comment: Trademark protection doesn't prevent you from using the trademarked name altogether.  It prohibits competitors from using the trademarked name for their competing product or service.  So it should not be necessary for you to refrain from using the name.

Comment: I think you're in the clear. You could totally go for something like this. (FYI I'm not a lawyer)

Comment: @everyone thanks for the input. I may just do this if I feel like it will be a worthy endeavor. Worst case I'll just get a cease and desist right :P

Comment: How would you obtain a second to second list of tickets already purchased?

Comment: @DJohnM I wouldn't, it says in the description users would sum it them

Comment: Also, there are *292 million* possible tickets, not 2.92 million.